# How do you store an array given as input?

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm fairly new to Java and am having difficulties inputting arrays from the command line. For example, if I ran my program using:

```
java ChessTournament {0,2,4,3,3,2,4,3,0,3} {1923,1882,2103,2210}
```

How would I then store these in two separate integer arrays?

Since the argument in main gives all inputs as a list of strings, the only way I have found is to use `string.replace()` on brackets and `string.split()` on commas (see below) but surely there's an easier way...?

This is what I have done until now for inputs of type `String[]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String[] arrival = new String[args[0].length()];
  args[0] = args[0].replace("{","");
  args[0] = args[0].replace("}","");
  arrival = (args[0]).split(",");

  String[] departure = new String[args[1].length()];
  args[1] = args[1].replace("{","");
  args[1] = args[1].replace("}","");
  departure = (args[1]).split(",");

}
```

Comment: can you share what code you have done so far with us?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest mechanism is probably to use a Scanner. Something like:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args[0]).useDelimeter("[{},]");
while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    intList.add(scanner.nextInt());
```

Comment: Guess `arg1` is the first argument given to the Java program, from `main(String[] args)` (`arg1 = args[0]`)

Comment: Used arg1 to make it more generic but changed it to args[0] to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is honestly pretty solid. I think it's fairly terse, and it's probably about as good as you're going to get in a language like Java. That said, there are two main problems I see:

1. It doesn't handle situations in which the arguments aren't formatted properly.
2. It doesn't parse the individual values to numbers.

You can fix both of these problems fairly elegantly using regular expressions and Java 8 streams.

```
public static int[] parseIntegerArray(String data) {
    if (!data.matches("^\\{(\\d+,)*\\d+?\\}$"))
        throw new RuntimeException("Malformed integer array.");
    return Arrays.stream(data.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split(","))
                 .mapToInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(x))
                 .toArray();
}
```

You can then use this function from `main` like this:

```
if (args.length < 2)
    throw new RuntimeException("Requires two array arguments.");
int[] arrival = parseIntegerArray(args[0]);
int[] departure = parseIntegerArray(args[1]);
```

[You can see a running example at ideone here.](http://ideone.com/dZJ5PY)

Comment: Not very familiar with Java 8 streams, but will do some reading. Thanks for your help!